# How to handle keyboard events on a document level in ReacJS

Tags: reactjs, keyboard-shortcuts

I want to implement keyboard shortcuts in a React App. I am quite new to React. How do we do this? I don't want to use any plugins.

Let's say I want to close a Modal on <kbd>Esc</kbd>.

```
class Modal extends React.Component{

componentWillMount(){
    document.addEventListener("keydown",closeModal);//creating problems
} 
componentWillUnMount(){
    document.removeEventListener("keydown",closeModal);
 }
closeModal(){
   //closing code
}

render(){
   //render code
}
}
```

Now how to listen to <kbd>Esc</kbd> event and call closeModal when that happens? Adding a event listener for document in componentWillMount is creating problems as it is changing "this" value to "document"

Answer (score 1):

Bind correct context (`this`) to the passed event handlers:

```js
document.addEventListener("keydown", this.closeModal.bind(this));
```

This is simple example. You probably want to bind your methods in constructor so that you will be able to remove event listener. E.g.:

```js
class Modal extends React.Component{

    constructor(props, ctx) {
        super(props, ctx);
        this.closeModal = this.closeModal.bind(this);
    }

    componentWillMount(){
        document.addEventListener("keydown", this.closeModal);
    }

    componentWillUnMount(){
        document.removeEventListener("keydown", this.closeModal);
    }

    closeModal(){
        //closing code
    }

}
```

Comment: I actually did that. It still shows this as document in closeModal function

Comment: Refactor closeModal function as the following to handle keyboard event, event parameter is needed:  closeModal(e){
      if(e.keyCode === 27){
          //closing code
      }   
    }

Comment: I did: if (event.key === 'Escape') {

Seemed a bit more readable for my peers.